# Can i move a database from one filesystem to another by moving it's raw data?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux / mysql: is it safe to copy mysql db files with cp command from one db to another?](https://serverfault.com/questions/367255/linux-mysql-is-it-safe-to-copy-mysql-db-files-with-cp-command-from-one-db-to)

`mysqldump` will take 5 hours to run. I have no idea of how much it will take to restore the tables; the database is 300GB in size.

Can't i just shutdown mysql and copy the raw data? Please note that i also want to rebuild (destroy and recreate) the innodb log files. I will use the same version of MySQL and InnoDB (xtradb) is my storage engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure. You can shutdown mysql server and copy the data dir to another partition or machine. Then, you can start mysql server after checking the permissions.

You should be fine while you are moving through similar platforms. Otherwise, you may face troubles and then you should revert back to using `mysqldump`.