# MySQL Tables read only after move from failing HD

Tags: mysql

I have a wordpress site on a server that had a failing HD.  The drive went to read-only and I was able to copy off the mysql database files.
When I put those files onto another server and brought the site up, I'm seeing a ton of errors in the web server log about tables being read-only.

What I've tried that has not resolved it:

changing ownership to mysql:mysql (was already that way anyway)
stopping and starting mysql
repairing the tables -> gave a bunch of errors such as
*error    : Table 'ccon.wp_bwwc_btc_addresses' is read only*

Did not try rebooting the whole system.  Not sure what else I should try - they're still read-only.  Appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Created a new database, copied the table as per the first answer here: [Linux / mysql: is it safe to copy mysql db files with cp command from one db to another?](https://serverfault.com/questions/367255/linux-mysql-is-it-safe-to-copy-mysql-db-files-with-cp-command-from-one-db-to)
made sure that copied table was writable, copied the files over the existing tables and it was no longer writable.

seems like there must be a ro flag set on the whole db or something?  I guess one solution will be to copy all the tables into a new db and scrap the old db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as root.
Ensure that the permissions are appropriate.

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

Validate the 'user' privileges (from mysql prompt):

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like "'user'%";
```

Last, but not least, check the SELinux status and disable temporally if is enabled:

```
cat /selinux/enforce 
1

echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Reboot MySQL:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

To make selinux permanently disabled, set the SELINUX variable in the /etc/selinux/config file to 'disable'.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  omg i had just assumed selinux was off, that was it!  thanks!!